# C# connection google docs excel(spreadsheets)

Tags: c#, excel, connection, google-sheets-api

I need c# asp.net connection google docs excel(spreadsheets). I insert with c# in data and insert spreadsheets. How do I?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: nothing , just table ready and open visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)

You need first to download the [.NET library for the Google Data API](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list) and then start using the Sheets Api as mentionned in the first link.